# FOP is it possible to create a table with only <table-head> but no <table-body>?

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

I'm using FOP to transform HTML(embedded in XML) to PDF.
The HTML snippet is like below:-

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody/>
</table>
```

When I transform, I get this error:-

```
Caused by: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: Error(Unknown location): fo:table-body i
s missing child elements.
Required Content Model: marker* (table-row+|table-cell+)
```

I got the similar error when removing the `<tbody/>` element:-

```
org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: Error(Unknown location): fo:table is missing child
elements.
Required Content Model: (marker*,table-column*,table-header?,table-footer?,table-body+)
```

Looks like table-body is required to fo:table and table-row is required to table-body. My question is:-

Is it possible to create a table with only table-header and without table-body or with an empty table-body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ofcourse, the the following way:

1. Create the `<fo:table-body>`
2. Create  `<fo:table-cell`s even if it requires
3. Put the border size zero and color white, or the color of your page
   background

Answer (score 0):

If your data xpath is xpa/th, you can use the following:

```
<fo:table>
    <fo:table-header>(whatever)</fo:table-header>
    <fo:table-body>
        <xsl:if test="xpa/th">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xpa/th" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(xpa/th)">
            <fo:table-cell><fo:block /></fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:if>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```